# Determining the value of a position on an array based on its nearest datapoint known value

Tags: python, array, vectorization

I was wondering what would be the efficient way to determine the value of a position on an array based on its nearest datapoint known value in Python?

> **Problem description:**
>
> There are datapoints in an array which are 1000 units apart and their values are known (see the figure). However,
>   there are datapoints which fall between the known datapoints and their
>   values should be determined based on their nearest known datapoint.
>
> For instance, following the figure, the value of the datapoint at
>   position 124200 should be set to 435 and the value of the datapoint at
>   position 124850 should be set to 380.
>
> [image: determining the value of a position on an array based on its nearestdatapoint known value]

At the moment, I am doing it like this:

```
# 'values' is an array which has the values for the known datapoints 
# 'position' is an array that has the datapoints which their values should be determined
# 'step' keeps the number of units in between two datapoints with known values
# 'n' is a list which keeps the extracted values

for pos in positions:
    if pos % step <= 500:
        idx = (( pos - (pos % step)) / step) - 1
        n.append(values[idx])
    else:       #pos % step > 500:
        idx = (( pos + (step - (pos % step))) / step)  - 1
       n.append(values[idx])
```

I was also considering implementing the logic with addition and subtraction operations instead of modulo and division operations, but after some discussion with a friend, we came up with the conclusion that modern processors in doing divisions and multiplication are as fast as doing addition and subtraction, so I ruled that option out.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use addition, subtraction, multiplication, division or modulo if your code isn't performance critical. More importantly is the clarity of your code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following code answers my question:

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.around(np.array(positions) / step).astype(int)
for idx in indices:
    n.append(values[idx])
```

**EDIT**

I came up with the idea that the above code can become even more efficient by removing the for loop as below:

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.around(np.array(positions) / step).astype(int)
n = values[indices]
```

Comment: Consider replacing `idx` with `i`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an application of rounding.

```
idx = int(round(float(pos) / step)) - 1
```

Note, however, that the result in case `pos` is exactly halfway into a step is different from your code, and also differs between Python versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also came up with the following answer myself: 
`indices = np.around(positions / step).astype(int)`